# Can we implement nginx as a reverse proxy in red hat openshift?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, redhat, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have configured nginx as reverse proxy one pod in openshift and nginx webserver in another pod.
I am able to curl each service individually (proxy, webserver) but i am unable to proxy my request to webserver.
I mean , When I curl nginx proxy url it should show nginx webserver page, rather than showing its own page.

the link to our config/yaml files are below:

https://github.com/MuhammadMunir12/nginx-config-files

Comment: Are you trying to build an ingress controller?

Comment: we have  tried nginx ingress controller from operator hub but it was not working, crashloopback error occures. thats why we are using nginx as reverse proxy.

Comment: from the deployment on the git repo it looks like you arent mounting the specific files or configurations in the `volumeMounts` section from the config map. is that making sense to you?

Comment: Try harder with the nginx ingress controller. Fixing that is far easier than what you're trying to do, and pretty standard. Forget the operator hub, try going to the github repo and following their installation instructions, which start with a simple helm chart.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer thats the issue i am not using kubernets i am using openshift. which they say we dont support ingress controller

Comment: I feel your pain. Have you read this? https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/using-nginx-ingress-controller-red-hat-openshift

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer yes, but operator is not working in my case.

Answer (score 0):

OpenShift comes with a router out of the box, which is RedHat's abstraction of an ingress.

Using [nginx as a router](https://github.com/nginxinc/nginx-openshift-router) has been an option during OpenShift v3 but is not supported (or working) in the v4 Architecture.

However, what your are trying to do, can be achieved by using `route`.
The [documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.9/networking/routes/route-configuration.html) guides you along.

With your current deployment you can try it out like follows:

```
oc expose nginx-deployment-ws
oc expose svc nginx-deployment-ws
```

This will create a route with a subdomain to your clusters domain, making your webserver available

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to hear that you are having problems with the nginx operator. I've just tried the nginx operator myself and it seems to be working fine actually. However it was also updated a couple of days you posted, currently running at version 0.5.0. Maybe try again? If it still doesn't work and you have  OpenShift subscription, you can actually open a support case with Red Hat on this. All certified operators,  like nginx, come with first-level support triage.

PS: I am Product Manager at Red Hat, associated with that part of OpenShift.

Comment: Thank you for responding!. have you implemented a reverse proxy using nginx? or you have just implemented router? can you share your yamls.

Comment: I have just done a standard nginx deployment with the operator to see if there is a general problem either with the operator images or the nginx images. If you can share you config files that would help.